# Craft CMS 3 Remote DB SSL connection

Tags: craftcms

I have added this to the db.php file, and am now trying to get craft setup over `/admin/install`. However, the database screen still reports that unsecured transport connections are not allowed. What's the gripe?

```
'attributes' => [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => '/config/ssl/key.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT   => '/config/ssl/cert.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA     => '/config/ssl/ca.pem',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

An array of key => value pairs of PDO attributes to pass into the PDO constructor.

For example, when using the MySQL PDO driver (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php),

if you wanted to enable an SSL database connection (assuming SSL is enabled in MySQL
(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-secure-connections.html) and `'user'`
 can connect via SSL, you'd set these:

```
php
[     
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => '/path/to/my/client-key.pem',
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT   => '/path/to/my/client-cert.pem',
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA     => '/path/to/my/ca-cert.pem',
],
```

list of the available settings in vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/DbConfig.php